# How do I filter in a listview with Search View?

Tags: java, android

I want to add searchview to my notepad application made with sqlite

I have an sqlite notebook application. I want to add searchview to this application to search users notes. but i am having some problems. I don't know how to add it.When I want to add, I write searchview, but the application exits, how do I solve it?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static veritabanı veritabanim;
    ListView list_view;
    private TextView myNot,mySaat,myTarih;
    private SearchView searchView;

    int images[]= {R.drawable.ic_note};

    private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList arrayList;
    private MyAdapter adapter;


    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       list_view=findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchview);

        veritabanim= Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),veritabanı.class,"notdb").allowMainThreadQueries().build();
       Button btn_notekle=findViewById(R.id.btnnotekle);




       btn_notekle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),notekle.class);
               startActivity(intent);
           }
       });

        List<Not> notlar= MainActivity.veritabanim.dao().getNot();
         arrayList=new ArrayList();

        ArrayList n=new ArrayList();
        ArrayList s=new ArrayList();
        ArrayList t=new ArrayList();



        String veriler="";

        for (Not nt:notlar){
            int id=nt.getId();
            String nnotsaat=nt.getNotsaat();
            String nnottarih=nt.getNottarih();
            String nnot=nt.getNot();

            veriler=veriler+nnot+nnotsaat+nnottarih;
            arrayList.add(veriler);
            veriler="";





            n.add(nnot);
            s.add(nnotsaat);
            t.add(nnottarih);

        }



        arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);

         adapter=new MyAdapter(this, n,s,t,images);
        list_view.setAdapter(adapter);
        Not not = new Not();


        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                not.getNot().toLowerCase().contains(newText);


                return false;


            }
        });


        list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {


                AlertDialog.Builder diyalogOlusturucu = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);


                long veriid=arrayAdapter.getItemId(position);
                String listeid=String.valueOf(veriid);


                diyalogOlusturucu.setMessage("Not Silinsin mi?")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Evet", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                veriSil(listeid);
                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton("Hayır", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                dialogInterface.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                diyalogOlusturucu.create().show();
            }
        });

    }

    private void veriSil(String listeid){


        List<Not> notlarsil=MainActivity.veritabanim.dao().getNot();
        ArrayList arrayListSil=new ArrayList();

        int veriler;
        for (Not silliste : notlarsil){
            int id = silliste.getId();
            veriler=id;
           arrayListSil.add(veriler);
           veriler=0;
        }
             String Sid=listeid;
        int id=Integer.valueOf(Sid);
        int eleman=(int) arrayListSil.get(id);

        Not not=new Not();
        not.setId(eleman);
        MainActivity.veritabanim.dao().notSil(not);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not Silindi.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
        startActivity(getIntent());
    }
        class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String >{
        Context context;
        ArrayList rNot;
        ArrayList rSaat;
        ArrayList rTarih;
        int rImg[];
        MyAdapter(Context c,ArrayList not, ArrayList saat, ArrayList tarih,int imgs[]){

            super(c, R.layout.custom_view, R.id.txtnot, not);
            this.context=c;
            this.rNot= not;
            this.rSaat=saat;
            this.rTarih=tarih;
            this.rImg=images;


        }



        @NonNull
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent){
             LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View row=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, parent, false);
            ImageView images=row.findViewById(R.id.resim);
             myNot=row.findViewById(R.id.txtnot);
             mySaat=row.findViewById(R.id.txtsaat);
             myTarih=row.findViewById(R.id.txttarih);



            images.setImageResource(rImg[0]);
            myNot.setText((CharSequence) rNot.get(position));
            mySaat.setText((CharSequence) rSaat.get(position));
            myTarih.setText((CharSequence) rTarih.get(position));



            return row;

        }


        }
    }
```

Not.java

```
@Entity(tableName = "notlar")
public class Not {
    @PrimaryKey
    public int id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "not")
    public String not;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "saat")
    public String notsaat;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "tarih")
    public String nottarih;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNot() {
        return not;
    }

    public void setNot(String not) {
        this.not = not;
    }

    public String getNotsaat() {
        return notsaat;
    }

    public void setNotsaat(String notsaat) {
        this.notsaat = notsaat;
    }

    public String getNottarih() {
        return nottarih;
    }

    public void setNottarih(String nottarih) {
        this.nottarih = nottarih;
    }
}
```